# Parse multiple href within one parent using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have one line in my program, using BeautifulSoup's find():

```
print(table.find('td','monsters'))
```

This is the output of the above line:

```
<td class="monsters">
<a href="/m154"><div class="mim mim-154"></div></a>
<a href="/m153"><div class="mim mim-153"></div></a>
<a href="/m152"><div class="mim mim-152"></div></a>
<a href="/m155"><div class="mim mim-155"></div></a>
<a href="/m147"><div class="mim mim-147"></div></a>
</td>
```

Now I want to parse all five hrefs, so that it would output something like this:

```
/m154
/m153
/m152
/m155
/m147
```

I have attempted to convert my `print` line into a for loop by changing `find()` to `find_all()`, and then retrieve the href by using `.a['href']` within the foor loop. However, no matter what I try, I would always only get one entry instead of five. Any suggestions for retrieving multiple href? Seeing that `find_all()` returns an array, would it make sense to make find_all() directly above the parent of `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
page = """<td class="monsters">
<a href="/m154"><div class="mim mim-154"></div></a>
<a href="/m153"><div class="mim mim-153"></div></a>
<a href="/m152"><div class="mim mim-152"></div></a>
<a href="/m155"><div class="mim mim-155"></div></a>
<a href="/m147"><div class="mim mim-147"></div></a>
</td>"""


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser") # your source page parsed as html
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True) # get all links having href attribute
for i in links:
    print(i['href'])
```

Result:

```
/m154
/m153
/m152
/m155
/m147
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the `links` within your code is just anything with the `a` tag, is that right?

Comment: yes, if you want to classify it then you can with another tag(parent or sub tag) or with class/id of tag

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is something like the following:

```
cell = table.find('td', 'monsters')
for a_tag in cell.find_all('a'):
  print(a['href'])
```

Comment: this answer works also if there is more html code than just the table.

Answer (score 0):

Full Code, similar to posts above

```
import bs4


HTML= """<html>
            <table>
                <tr>
                <td class="monsters">
                    <a href="/m154"><div class="mim mim-154"></div></a>
                    <a href="/m153"><div class="mim mim-153"></div></a>
                    <a href="/m152"><div class="mim mim-152"></div></a>
                    <a href="/m155"><div class="mim mim-155"></div></a>
                    <a href="/m147"><div class="mim mim-147"></div></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </html>
        """

table = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
anker = table.find('td', 'monsters').find_all('a')
[print(a['href']) for a in anker]
```